# How to support sorting and filtering for a field which is not mapped with another entity using spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-projections

I have an entity `Person` which has fields `id,name,email`

Another entity `Employee` which has fields `id,name,personid` (stores the string id of person but not mapped with person table)

Now I want to get paginated list which contains person name, employee id, employee name along with searching and sorting based on person name and employee name dynamically.
i.e., User can sort by person name or employee name and filter by person name or employee name or both

In query format we can write,

```sql
select emp.id,emp.name,p.name from employee emp join person p on
emp.personid=p.id
```

This query returns expected output but to achieve searching and sorting, i'm unable to use projections as personid in Employee entity is not mapped with id of Person entity.

Criteria builder shouldn't be used and entities cannot be changed.

It would be greatly appreciated if someone could provide a best and optimal solution to get the required paginated result which supports sorting and filtering.

Answer (score 1):

You could modify existing query with `order by` clause and pass `Pageable`, e.g. here is the example of sorting by employee name:

```java
@Query("select emp.id,emp.name,p.name from employee emp join person p on emp.personid=p.id order by emp.name")
Page<YourDto> findAllOrderByEmployyNamePersonName(Pageable pageable);
```

For filtering by employee name just add `where` clause:

```java
@Query("select emp.id,emp.name,p.name from employee emp join person p on emp.personid=p.id where emp.name = :empName")
Page<YourDto> findByEmployeeName(String empName, Pageable pageable);
```

Comment: Can you pls check the edited question. Based on user clicks on any column either person name or employee name for sorting or filtering dynamically, we need to sort/filter that particular field

Comment: In this case, we will have to write 3 queries, 2 for individual column filtering and last one for filtering both columns. Can you please share an alternative like to filter or sort a column dynamically when user selects on it instead of writing multiple queries for filtering each column

Comment: For this you need CustomRepoImpl, see https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.custom-implementations

Comment: Thanks for the link.You mean we need to create an impl and write multiple queries for each filter? Can you suggest efficient solution for this problem other than writing many queries.

Comment: You could construct the query in custom repository e.g. by appending filtering/ordering clauses to select depending on arguments

Comment: @SnehaSreePashikanti Pageable has option to pass sort options,
See how we create Pageable object wherever you are calling the query

```java
Pageable pageable = PageRequest.of(0, 5, Sort.by(
    Order.asc("name"),
    Order.desc("id")));
```
You can also pass existing pageable and create Page
ref:
https://reflectoring.io/spring-boot-paging/

you will have single query but with `Pageable` variations based on your conditional logic